# MS Edge debugger (chromium) - stop threads, call stack, scope...etc. panels automatically expanding

Tags: debugging, layout, microsoft-edge

I use the Chromium version of MS Edge a LOT when debugging.

99% of my use of the debugger involved adding watches and I'm not usually interested in much else.  Accordingly, I usually format the panel to look like this:

[image: How I want it]

BUT, if I ever refresh the page, or move the debugger window, it automatically collapses and expands panels and gives me this:

[image: How it reformats]

This is pretty annoying and I just wish that it would remember my preference for how these panels are arranged as it would save so much time.  I know it's only a few seconds to collapse everything except the Watch panel, but if you are doing that hundreds of times a day....it adds up.

Is there any way that anyone know of to make Edge remember how the panels are arranged?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I check it using Edge Version 81.0.416.64 (Official build) (64-bit), if I refresh the page or move the F12 window,  it will remember the collapses and expands panels. But if I close the F12 developer tools window and reopen, it will not remember the collapses and expands panels, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bV8w.png)(the default status).

Besides, according to this question, I suppose you could try to send Microsoft Edge team your feedback using the Send feedback icon, and ask them to try to add a new feature to remember the watch panel's status for personal.

[image]